# python- input problem in chat client (threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I'm building a multithreaded chat client in python. When the client first connect to the server, the server sends a welcome message to the client. However, this message is mostly messed up with the input part. If the input prompt in the client part is "Me:", the output becomes like "Me:Your nickname is Monique Williams".(The second part is sent by the server, which appoints a random fake name to the client connected).

How can I prevent this? I know it's because of multithreading and I tried using time.sleep() but it didn't work.

```
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread
import os
import time


HOST="192.168.1.33"
PORT=5000

try:
  os.system("color A")
  s = socket.socket()
  s.connect((HOST,PORT))



  def recv():
     while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if not data: sys.exit(0)
        print(data.decode())

  t1=Thread(target=recv)
  t1.start()



  while 1:
     message = input("Me:")
     s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))


except ConnectionRefusedError:
  print("Server Error!")
```

Comment: How do you know that this is due to multi-threading?

Comment: @Moralous: In a way it is, since the threads do not cooperate in writing to `stdout`. Typically, the main thread prints `"Me:"` and then while waiting for input, the second thread gets a message from the server, which is printed where-ever the cursor happens to be (which is directly after `"Me:"`, waiting for input).

Comment: How would you *like* your program to handle this? First of all you need an idea of what should happen when you receive a message from the server and when you would like to accept user input.

Comment: Well, I want the server message to come first (when the program first opens) and "Me:" prompt to come in the second line.

Comment: @suleymanyaman Do you have any kind of handshake protocol going on?